# How to add string values before header for a csv file in scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, header

I am having a csv file with no header. I want to add headers and also string values before header. Final file should look like below image.
[image]

where first row values are string values and 2nd row is column names, from 3rd row data.

I am able add header using seq in scala - spark. But not able to add first row.
How can I add first row as well using scala.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option for csv-write in `spark` to get several rows into csv-file before header.

But maybe you can rename your first column to include your required rows like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  (1, "a", "test a"),
  (2, "b", "test b"),
  (3, "c", "test c")
).toDF("id", "code", "description")

df.show
+---+----+-----------+
| id|code|description|
+---+----+-----------+
|  1|   a|     test a|
|  2|   b|     test b|
|  3|   c|     test c|
+---+----+-----------+

val firstRow = "This,is,sample\n" + df.columns(0)
df.withColumnRenamed(df.columns(0), firstRow).show
+------------------+----+-----------+
|This,is,sample\nid|code|description|
+------------------+----+-----------+
|1                 |a   |test a     |
|2                 |b   |test b     |
|3                 |c   |test c     |
+------------------+----+-----------+

(
  df
  .withColumnRenamed(df.columns(0), firstRow)
  .coalesce(1)
  .write.mode("overwrite")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("quote","")
  .csv("testspark.csv")
)
```

Comment: Could you please help me with what's happening here.

Comment: Sure, but what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: How it is going to add a row.

Comment: val firstRow = "This,is,sample\n" + df.columns(0) <-- it's here, we prepend "This,is,sample" + newline to name of first column

Comment: Then how data is added

Comment: you have a tag on your question - "apache-spark". So I gave you the solution for apache-spark. If you are not familiar with spark yet, then here's a good place to start: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: As because, As per your answer df.column(0) will take only 1st column, then how data will be mapped

Comment: I edited my answer. Just run the code and see if it works for you.